# awk/sed for test command

Tags: awk, ksh

from my ksh I have

```
  [[  ` echo $READ_LINE | awk '{print $2}' ` != SOME_WORD  ]] && print "not match"
```

can I get suggestion how to verify the same without echo command? ( maybe awk/sed is fine for this? )

lidia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
awk -v x="$READ_LINE" -v y="SOME_WORD" 'BEGIN { split(x, a); if (a[2] != y) print "not match";}'
```

But where does `$READ_LINE` come from? What are you trying to accomplish? There might just also is a good plain `sh` or `ksh` solution.

I highly doubt your claim that `echo` (which might be a shell builtin) takes more time than `awk`. Here is a `plain sh` version:

```
set -- $READ_LINE
[ x$2 != xSOME_WORD] && echo "not match"
```

But the `ksh` [solution of Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598847/awk-sed-for-test-command/3599262#3599262) looks the best for your situation.

Comment: the target is to save time (echo take time awk not)

Answer (score 0):

```
read ign val && [ X$val != XSOME_WORD ] && echo "not match"
```

Answer (score 0):

This splits the line by words and tests the second word.

```
var=($READ_LINE)
[[  ${var[1]} != SOME_WORD  ]] && print "not match"
```

What is it you're trying to accomplish? Several of your questions are nearly identical.

Comment: var=($READ_LINE) isnt valid syntax in ksh!

Comment: @lidia: What version of ksh? Are you using `#!/bin/ksh`, `#!/usr/bin/ksh` or `#!/bin/sh` as the first line of your script (the shebang)?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ksh, then just use the shell without having to call external commands

```
set -- $READ_LINE
case "$2" in
  "SOME_WORD" ) echo "found";;
esac
```

Why are you still tacking this problem since I see you have other threads similar to this.?